# Reset Auto Nav Function on hover in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have divs that automatically cycle to the next div and show its contents after every few seconds. The same content is also shown when the corresponding link is hovered. The functionality works fine however can the auto nav function be reset such that when the mouse leaves the link the auto nav starts from the first link? Below is the code:

```js
$(function() {

  var homeLinks = ['i-t', 'o-c', 'c-f', 'i-c', 'c-u'];
  var currentLink = 0;
  var hovered = false;

  $(".home-link").hover(function() {
    hovered = true;
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    currentLink = homeLinks.indexOf($(this).attr('data-hover'));
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
  }, function() {
    hovered = false;
  });

  setTimeout(() => {
    var autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 3000);
  }, 000);

  function autoNav() {
    if (hovered === false) {
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      currentLink++;
      if (currentLink >= homeLinks.length) {
        currentLink = 1;
      }
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.left-fill {
  background: #0000006b;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right-fill {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vc_col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline::after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover)::after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.home-o-c,
.home-c-f,
.home-i-c,
.home-c-u {
  display: none;
}

.our-company {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}

.cf2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-fill text-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p class="home-i-t">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-o-c">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-c-f">TExt for C f.</p>
    <p class="home-i-c">Some more text fo i c.</p>
    <p class="home-c-u">Get in touch </p>

  </div>
</div>



<div class="home-fill right-fill text-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <ul class="pivot-nav">
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="o-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="c-f" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="i-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2"><a data-hover="c-u" class="home-link" href="#">C U</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `mouseout` event as follows:

```js
$('.wpb_wrapper').on('mouseout touchend touchcancel', function() {
  reset();
  start();
})

function start() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 3000);
  }, 000);
}

function reset() {
  clearInterval(autoNavInterval);
  currentLink = 0;
  homeLinks.forEach(function(element) {
    $('[data-hover=' + element + ']').removeClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + element).hide();
  });
  $('.home-' + homeLinks[0]).show();
  hovered = false;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  var homeLinks = ['i-t', 'o-c', 'c-f', 'i-c', 'c-u'];
  var currentLink = 0;
  var hovered = false;
  var autoNavInterval;

  $(".home-link").hover(function() {
    hovered = true;
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    currentLink = homeLinks.indexOf($(this).attr('data-hover'));
    $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
  }, function() {
    hovered = false;
  });

  function start() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      autoNavInterval = setInterval(autoNav, 3000);
    }, 000);
  }
  
  function reset() {
    clearInterval(autoNavInterval);
    currentLink = 0;
    homeLinks.forEach(function(element) {
      $('[data-hover=' + element + ']').removeClass('default-underline');
      $('.home-' + element).hide();
    });
    $('.home-' + homeLinks[0]).show();
    hovered = false;
  }

  function autoNav() {
    if (hovered === false) {
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).hide();
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      currentLink++;
      if (currentLink >= homeLinks.length) {
        currentLink = 1;
      }
      $('[data-hover=' + homeLinks[currentLink] + ']').toggleClass('default-underline');
      $('.home-' + homeLinks[currentLink]).show();
    }
  }
  
  start();
  
  $('.wpb_wrapper').on('mouseout touchend touchcancel', function() {
    reset();
    start();
  });
});
```

```css
.left-fill {
  background: #0000006b;
  height: 100vh;
}

.right-fill {
  background: pink;
  height: 100vh;
}

.vc_col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.pivot-nav {
  list-style: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  text-align: left;
}

.pivot-nav li a {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.pivot-nav li a.default-underline::after,
.pivot-nav li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.pivot-nav:hover a.default-underline:not(:hover)::after {
  width: 0;
}

.pivot-nav li a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.home-o-c,
.home-c-f,
.home-i-c,
.home-c-u {
  display: none;
}

.our-company {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}

.cf2 {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-fill text-left wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p class="home-i-t">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-o-c">TEXT One</p>
    <p class="home-c-f">TExt for C f.</p>
    <p class="home-i-c">Some more text fo i c.</p>
    <p class="home-c-u">Get in touch </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="home-fill right-fill text-right wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <ul class="pivot-nav">
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="o-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="c-f" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-hover="i-c" class="home-link" href="#" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
      <li class="pivot-nav-item" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2"><a data-hover="c-u" class="home-link" href="#">C U</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fine however when the mouse leaves the link, there is a slight time gap and the box on the left is blank for a few seconds. It needs to show TEXT one immediately.  And Mouse out would not work on touch devices?

Comment: you could add `$('.home-' + homeLinks[0]).show();` to show the item in left box immediately, I'm really not sure about touch device though